# Modifying gradients stop training, PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, autograd

I am trying to train a pruned neural network which has (say) 36% sparsity which means that 36% of the trainable parameters are 0s. I am using a simple LeNet-300-100 dense network for this:

```py
class LeNet300(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Define layers-
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features = 28 * 28 * 1, out_features = 300)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features = 300, out_features = 100)
        self.output = nn.Linear(in_features = 100, out_features = 10)
        
        # self.weights_initialization()
    
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.leaky_relu(self.fc1(x))
        out = F.leaky_relu(self.fc2(out))
        return self.output(out)
```

After 36% sparsity, the number of trainable parameters = 213288. Originally, without pruning, it has 266610 non-zero parameters.

The layer-wise sparsity looks as:

```py
for param in model.parameters():
    print(f"{param.size()} has {torch.count_nonzero(param)} surviving weights")
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([300, 784]) has 146615 surviving weights
torch.Size([300]) has 300 surviving weights
torch.Size([100, 300]) has 22743 surviving weights
torch.Size([100]) has 100 surviving weights
torch.Size([10, 100]) has 862 surviving weights
torch.Size([10]) has 10 surviving weights
```

The code I am using to preserve sparsity is:

In .grad (`gradient_t`), replace computed gradients with 0s in place positions (within the matrix) where the trainable parameters (`wts`) are pruned:

```py
# Compute loss-
J = loss(outputs, labels)
            
# Empty accumulated gradients-
optimizer.zero_grad()
            
# Perform backprop-
J.backward()
            
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    wts = param.data.clone().detach()
    gradient_t = param.grad
    gradient_t = torch.where(wts == 0., 0., gradient_t)
    param.grad = gradient_t
        
# Update parameters-
optimizer.step()
```

However, after this, the training basically freezes, and the loss and accuracy stop changing.

?